# dataProvider is 0x0 / nil (GPUImage Framework)

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I wrote some code which creates a filter and can be controlled via a UISlider.
But if I slide the UISlider, the app crashes.

**My code:**

**.m file:**

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

    [_sliderBrightness addTarget:self action:@selector(brightnessFilter) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    _sliderBrightness.minimumValue = -1.0;
    _sliderBrightness.maximumValue = 1.0;
    _sliderBrightness.value = 0.0;
}

- (IBAction)sliderBrightness:(UISlider *)sender {

    CGFloat midpoint = [(UISlider *)sender value];
    [(GPUImageBrightnessFilter *)brightFilter setBrightness:midpoint - 0.1];
    [(GPUImageBrightnessFilter *)brightFilter setBrightness:midpoint + 0.1];

    [sourcePicture processImage];
}


- (void) brightnessFilter {

    UIImage *inputImage = _imgView.image;

    sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
    brightFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];

    GPUImageView *imgView2 = (GPUImageView *)self.view;

    [brightFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
    [sourcePicture addTarget:brightFilter];

    [sourcePicture processImage];

    UIImage* outputImage = [brightFilter imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation:0];
    [_imgView setImage:outputImage];
}
```

Error:

```
GPUImageFramebuffer.m:

}
        else
        {
            [self activateFramebuffer];
            rawImagePixels = (GLubyte *)malloc(totalBytesForImage);
            glReadPixels(0, 0, (int)_size.width, (int)_size.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, rawImagePixels);
            dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, rawImagePixels, totalBytesForImage, dataProviderReleaseCallback);
            [self unlock]; // Don't need to keep this around anymore
        }
```

In this line of code:

```
    [self activateFramebuffer];
```

Error message:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_1386_GPFLT)
```

Console:

```
self = (GPUImageFramebuffer *const) 0x10a0a6960
rawImagePixels = (GLubyte *) 0x190
dataProvider = (CGDataProviderRef) 0x0
renderTarget = (CVPixelBufferRef) 0x8
```

Maybe the dataProvider causes the crash but I don't really know because I'm new in developing iOS apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This obviously isn't going to work (and shouldn't even compile) because GPUImageBrightnessFilter has no `-setTopFocusLevel:` or `-setBottomFocusLevel:` method. You copied this from my sample application without changing these methods to the one appropriate to a brightness filter (which is the `brightness` property).

It's also rather confusing (and potentially problematic) to have both a `brightnessFilter` instance variable and `-brightnessFilter` method. You probably want to rename the former to make it clear that's where you're performing your initial setup of the filter and source image. You'll also need to call that in your view controller's setup (after your Nib is loaded).

Comment: I added already this 2 methods in the .m file of the brightness filter. But it still does not work. I renamed the instance variable.

Comment: Ok. Now I'm going another way. I do it in one method (code in my answer). All works fine if I slide the UISlider forwards. But if I slide the UISlider backwards, the filter is getting stronger. Do you know why?

Comment: @DeviJP - The cause of your problem is that you're applying your brightness to something that you've already applied the previous brightness pass to, rather than your source image. That's not what you want to do. Again, you really should not be recreating the picture and filter on every single change in value, and you should not be setting a UIImage to a UIImageView on each pass. Follow the example provided in the SimpleImageFilter example, where I create the GPUImagePicture and filter once, direct them to a GPUImageView, and only update the value of the filter to provide a live preview.

Comment: Ok. Now I've applied the filter like you've done it in your SimpleImageFilter example. I've also added the 2 methods -setTopFocusLevel and -setBottomFocusLevel in the GPUImageBrightnessFilter Class. But the filter isn't a brightness filter. It's like a blur filter and sometimes the app crashes. I posted the whole code in the question. Maybe you could have a look at it.

Comment: I have tried everything that has occurred to me. But it does not work still. Could you please help me one last time, or give a hint where I should look again? I wrote in my question where in my conjecture the cause is.